# C: Doubling each letter in a String

Tags: c

I am studying C as of now and I am stuck on this question.

```
Input: 'abc'
Output: 'aabbcc'
```

I am stuck with the pointers and increasing the size buffer. See below

Edit: added the main()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char destValue[];
   char srcValue[];    

   //User input
   printf("Please enter valid text: " );
   scanf("%s", srcValue);

   //Copying to memory
   memcpy(destValue, srcValue, strlen(srcValue)+1);
   char lenghtOfText = strlen(srcValue); 

   for(int i = 0; i < lenghtOfText; i++) {
      tempValue[i] = strcat(tempValue, srcValue);
   }
}
```

Every time I am running my code, it keeps on failing and the error message is Abort 6. Upon searching, they said the tempValue does not increase the size of the buffer.

Sorry, if my code isn't working and I am just learning C programming. Thanks for understanding

Comment: What is `tempValue`?

Comment: @alk char *tempValue; Sorry about that. I missed that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char* srcValue = "Hello World";
  char* output = calloc(strlen(srcValue)*2+1, sizeof(char));
  for (int i=0; i<strlen(srcValue); i++){
    output[2*i] = srcValue[i];
    output[2*i+1] = srcValue[i];
  }
  output[2*strlen(srcValue)] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", output);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `output[i+1] = srcValue[i];` - This is overwritten the next time around the loop

Comment: @script8man hi, thank you for your reply. Upon trying, it is giving me an out of 'aa?bcc'. I tried different string as well, it always gives me '?'. I don't know why.

Comment: @Shaun try a different length string and see where the '?' appears

Comment: @script8man tried the word 'Program' and the out is 'Prroo?grraamm'

Comment: @script8man I tried changing "\0" to '\0' but still no work. Now, it is not even displaying the output.

Comment: @Shaun I just tested the code, it functions perfectly. Please look carefully at what I put down.

Comment: `output[strlen(srcValue)-1]` is wrong, you need something like `output[2*i+2]`, one character after the last one you've written to.

Comment: @user4815162342 wouldn't `i` be overwritten after exiting the for loop?

Comment: @script8man I think it is working if the text(srcValue) is hardcoded. I tried it when the user will input a text, and it is not showing any output

Comment: @Shaun in the context of your question, that's irrelevant, try making sure the data inputed is the same as what you think it is.

Comment: `output[strlen(srcValue)-1] = '\0';` are you sure? Also `strlen(...) - 1` mostly always ends in a disaster for at least one corner case.

Comment: @alk yeah, I tried inputting Forward, but it is only outputing 'Ffoorr'. So I am thinking that too but I might be wrong.

Comment: BTW, as you `calloc()`ed `output` there isn't even the need to explicitly set the `0`-terminator^^. So you could just drop (the now correctly indexing) `output[2*strlen(srcValue)] = '\0';`.

Comment: @alk I prefer to use calloc over malloc as a general rule

Comment: "*prefer to use calloc over malloc*" performance wise not always to wisest decision.

Comment: @alk I appreciate the advice

Comment: @script8man You can declare `i` outside the loop, in which case it will remain available. It's wasteful to calculate `strlen` when not necessary. It's also wasteful to calculate `strlen(srcValue)` at every iteration. Your check could be `srcValue[i] != '\0'` (or simply `srcValue[i]`).

Comment: -1 because, despite being the accepted answer, this is **not** a good example of how C code is written. A C programmer would never execute `strlen` as loop condition of a string. Neither would they use `calloc` to allocate memory that is immediately overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

Simply You can do like this

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define len 10
int main()
{
        char *destValue;
        char *srcValue;

        srcValue = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        destValue = malloc((2 * len * sizeof(char)) + 1);
        //User input
        printf("Please enter valid text: " );
        scanf("%s", srcValue);
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0  ;srcValue[i]!= '\0';i++) {
                destValue[j++]= srcValue[i];
                destValue[j++]= srcValue[i];
        }

        destValue[j]='\0';
        puts(destValue);

        free(destValue);
        free(srcValue);

        return 0;
}
```

I hope you will get this.

Comment: `destValue = malloc(2 * len * sizeof(char));` off by one. This `destValue[j]= '\0';` writes beyond `destValue`'s bounds.

Comment: @alk  what's 'of by one'  didn't get ? it'll work in all case, len value can be taken from user.

Comment: @alk No, it's correct. when srcValue[i] reaches to NULL, j is there at correct position where it should be.

Comment: The adventurous with C is that seemingly working code does not need to be correct code. `destValue = malloc(2 * len * sizeof(char));` misses to allocate room for the `0`-terminator.

Comment: @alk okay i got it what you want to say , i edited my solution

Comment: And BTW, there is no `NULL` here. `NULL` is not the same as `NUL`.

Answer (score 0):

destValue and srcValue are essentially pointers to char arrays.  But you did not allocate any memory to them.  The scanf function will attempt to copy the entered text into an initialized memory location.